# How to put a header/foot close to the end of the paper?

Tags: header-footer

How can I put a header/foot closer to the end of the paper?

Do I have to use the fancyhdr package?

I tried but I had any problem, and I have in the first page the "numer page" in a different way from the rest of the pages.

Thank You.

[image]

Comment: So you want a different header/footer for the first page, perhaps something different for the middle of your document and then an even different one for the last page?

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the first page is a normal behaviour of LaTeX articles since usually headers and footers (except the number of page) have no sense in the title page. But if you want, you can change this with `\thispagestyle`.

For the end page you can simply redefine `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` in the last page. But personally I prefer simply a  `\vfill` followed by the note at the end. (I dislike the idea of a different header/footer for the last page because the lack consistency of the whole format, specially if the end note is at the level of the number of page (may be a bit confusing). A little example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhead[L]{Some}
\fancyhead[C]{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{header}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\title{Minimal Working Example}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-10] % dummy text
\vfill
\fancyhead[R]{end}
\fancyfoot[L]{This is a end footer}
This is a end note but not a footer
\end{document}
```